# Why is it possible to assign recursive lambdas to non-lazy vals in Scala?

Tags: scala, recursion, lambda, definition, specifications

In the following statement the val `f` is defined as a lambda that references itself (it is recursive):

```
val f: Int => Int = (a: Int) =>
    if (a > 10) 3 else f(a + 1) + 1 // just some simple function
```

I've tried it in the REPL, and it compiles and executes correctly.

According to the specification, this seems like an instance of illegal forward referencing:

> In a statement sequence `s[1]...s[n]` making up a block, if a simple
>   name in `s[i]` refers to an entity defined by `s[j]` where `j >= i`,
>   then for all `s[k]` between and including `s[i]` and `s[j]`,
>
> - `s[k]` cannot be a variable definition.
> - **If `s[k]` is a value definition, it must be `lazy`.**

The assignment is a single statement, so it satisfied the `j >= i` criteria, and it is included in the interval of statements the two rules apply to (between and including `s[i]` and `s[j]`).

However, it seems that it violates the second rule, because `f` is not lazy.

How is that a legal statement (tried it in Scala 2.9.2)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably tried to use this in the REPL, which wraps all contents in an object definition. This is important because in Scala (or better: on the JVM) all instance values are initialized with a default value, which is `null` for all `AnyRefs` and `0`, `0.0` or `false` for `AnyVals`. For method values this default initialization does not happen, therefore you get an error message in this case:

```
scala> object x { val f: Int => Int = a => if (a > 10) 3 else f(a+1)+1 }
defined object x

scala> def x { val f: Int => Int = a => if (a > 10) 3 else f(a+1)+1 }
<console>:7: error: forward reference extends over definition of value f
       def x { val f: Int => Int = a => if (a > 10) 3 else f(a+1)+1 }
                                                           ^
```

This behavior can even lead to weird situations, therefore one should be careful with recursive instance values:

```
scala> val m: Int = m+1
m: Int = 1

scala> val s: String = s+" x"
s: String = null x
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, this was in the REPL. I've had a hunch it might be something like that, I knew the Scala REPL had to have some black magic behind it (Scala is a compiled language after all, so I was a little confused when I saw it even had a REPL - I just assumed it collected all statements you typed before and put them in a `def main` or something).